# Python OpenCV with Skimage for Image Similarity

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I'm trying to get a proper program that compares two images and returns a score based on how similar they look. So, I watched several videos on how to do this, but nothing seems to return the correct answer because the closer the second image to the first one is, the lower the score gets.

So, I found this link that has a program that does exactly what I want.
[How-To: Python Compare Two Images](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/)

Now, after doing several testing the results are still wrong.

I have several images. The first image is the original and images 2-4 are just a portion of image 1 except that image 4 is very similar to image 1.
For example,
[image]

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

def mse(imageA, imageB):
    # the 'Mean Squared Error' between the two images is the
    # sum of the squared difference between the two images;
    # NOTE: the two images must have the same dimension
    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
    err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])

    # return the MSE, the lower the error, the more "similar"
    # the two images are
    return err
def compare_images(imageA, imageB, title):
    # compute the mean squared error and structural similarity
    # index for the images
    m = mse(imageA, imageB)
    s = ssim(imageA, imageB)
    # setup the figure
    fig = plt.figure(title)
    plt.suptitle("MSE: %.2f, SSIM: %.2f" % (m, s))
    # show first image
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(imageA, cmap = plt.cm.gray)
    plt.axis("off")
    # show the second image
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(imageB, cmap = plt.cm.gray)
    plt.axis("off")
    # show the images
    plt.show()

# load the images -- the original, the original + contrast,
# and the original + photoshop
original = cv2.imread("Test\i1.png")
contrast = cv2.imread("Test\i4.png")

# convert the images to grayscale
original = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contrast = cv2.cvtColor(contrast, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# initialize the figure
images = ("Original", original), ("Contrast", contrast)

# compare the images
compare_images(original, contrast, "Original vs. Contrast")
```

The problem with this is that if I test image 1 with image 2 it returns about an 80% match. But if I test image 1 with image 4 it returns a lower match at about 70%. Even though image 1 and image 4 look very similar, it's still not the same image. It should have returned something close to 90%.

Any idea on how can I fix this or if there is another method is a lot easier. By the way, I just started to learn openCV and Skimage.

Comment: it compares pixel-by-pixel, calculate different between two pixels (and power of two), and sum them. If two images have more black pixels in different places then they are more different. And `original` and `image` 4 has more black pixel in different places then `original` and `image 2` (or `image 3`) so it give worst result. It doesn't compare shapes on image. You could put all black pixels in different corners and you could get simillar results.

Comment: I figured it was something like that. Although, if it is calculating the total pixels, there is no reason why `image 2` gives a higher score than `image 4` when `image 4` has more pixel than `image 2-3`. Do you know what would be a better method of comparing these images to calculate how similar is `image 4` to `image 1` if put on top of each other?

Comment: if `image1` has 200 black pixels (in different places then other image) and `image 2-3` has 100 black pixels (in different places then other image) then difference is 300 pixels (200+100). And if `image 4` has more pixles so it may has 200 black pixels (in different places then other image) and then difference is bigger: 400 pixels (200+200). White image may gives better result because it will give 200+0 different black pixels. The best result you should get when you  compare with the same `image 1` because it has all black pixels in the same place so finally difference is 0 black pixels.

Comment: I don't know method to detect similar shape. Maybe it would need to calculate for small regions (ie. 5x5) instead of single pixels. OR maybe it would need `Neural Network`/`Convolutional Network` which are used to recognize ie. dogs/cats on image. They also use method with regions (ie. 5x5) to reduce original image to smaller image.

Comment: maybe you should ask on similar portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), eventually on [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: Thank you! My idea is to have `image 1` as the original image that will be used to compare the other images with. For example, images 2-4 are just for testing. The idea is to have a final image similar to `image 4` that looks very similar to `image 1` then compare both to see if `image 4` is somewhat similar to the original. After that get the score based on how similar 4 looks compared to 1. I'll take a look at the OpenCV forum.